# How to fetch the data btwn two diff date and time in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to fetch the data btwn two diff date and time in MongoDB

```
[
      {
        "key":"2",
        "start_date": "2023-01-03T03:30:00.000Z",
        "end_date": "2023-01-03T05:30:00.000Z",
        
      },
      {"key":"1",
        "start_date": "2023-01-04T03:30:00.000Z",
        "end_date": "2023-01-04T05:30:00.000Z",
        
      },
      {
        "key":"1",
        "start_date": "2023-01-05T03:30:00.000Z",
        "end_date": "2023-01-05T05:30:00.000Z",
        
      }
    ]

    db.collection.find({
      {"key":"2"},
      $or: [
        {
          start_date: {
            $gte: "2023-01-04T04:30:00.000Z",
            $lte: "2023-01-04T05:00:00.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          end_date: {
            $lte: "2023-01-04T05:00:00.000Z",
            $gte: "2023-01-04T04:30:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    })
```

I have two collection in database
Monday 10am to 11pm
Tuesday 10am to 11pm
Friday 11am to 12pm
how I will get the result if i find the Monday 10:30am to 10:45am, i want the result for btwn time also.
Query should return -

```
    [{
        "key":"2",
        "start_date": "2023-01-04T03:30:00.000Z",
        "end_date": "2023-01-04T05:30:00.000Z",
        
      }]
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Query should return the data 
[{
    "start_date": "2023-01-04T03:30:00.000Z",
    "end_date": "2023-01-04T05:30:00.000Z",
    
  }]

Comment: None of the provided input documents satisfy the date ranges you are querying for.  If you modify the conditions to actually include one of the documents, the query seems to work fine: https://mongoplayground.net/p/a41bHB4JrRy

Answer (score 0):

You start date for key:2 is "2023-01-03T03:30:00.000Z and end date is 2023-01-03T05:30:00.000Z so you can not get that record if your query for the

```
$or: [
    {
      start_date: {
        $gte: "2023-01-04T04:30:00.000Z",
        $lte: "2023-01-04T05:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    {
      end_date: {
        $lte: "2023-01-04T05:00:00.000Z",
        $gte: "2023-01-04T04:30:00.000Z"
      }
    }
  ]
```

This is clearly not matching the filter you are applying you have to start your date from "2023-01-03T03:30:00.000Z" and also please use $and operator. $or operator will match any of the start date or end dates. but if you want to get records that match both condition you have to use $and.

Comment: I have tried and operator but getting 0 results https://mongoplayground.net/p/2ee4Vf2a9MW

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/yJUdcA2sHNq,  using this query I am getting the accurate result, and if you want two results for key 1 and key 2 just remove the key:$eq: "2" as it is filtering the documents which contain the key value "2". or please describe your expected result.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it is a bit difficult to put it as comment.

You need to define clearly the condition what "between two diff date and time" means.
When your data has `start_date` and `end_date` and your query also have a date range (i.e. start and end) then you can have 6 different conditions. This table visualizes them:

```
          start_date         end_date         
    ------------------------------------------> time
(1)  x     x   |                |             
(2)        x   |           x    |             
(3)            |     x     x    |             
(4)            |     x          |    x        
(5)        x   |                |    x        
(6)            |                |    x    x
```

You need to define which of them are considered as true and false. Condition (1) and (6) are certainly `false` but what about the others?

In advanced case, you also have to consider documents where `start_date` or `end_date` is missing.

```
          start_date       undefined
    ------------------------------------------
(7)  x     x   |                             
(8)        x   |           x                 
(9)            |     x     x                 


           undefined         end_date         
    ------------------------------------------
(10)  x     x                   |             
(11)        x                   |    x        
(12)                            |    x    x
```